# Nissan Quashqui no power from 3rd gear up

Tags: nissan

Nissan Quashqui 1.6 diesel has no power from 3rd gear up. EGR delete and dpf delete and no fault codes coming up. Checked everything (I think and thinking it may be turbo now. Expensive to do if not problem. Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You can do some simple checks on your turbo, such as pulling the intake side off the turbo so you can access the compressor wheel to see how well it spins and if there's any play side to side (felt at the shaft). Also, check to see if there is oil while you're in there. Is there a lot of black exhaust smoke while driving at these speeds? This would also be a clue.

Comment: Do you have a reader that will tell you the running values? I can get turbo outlet pressure etc - that way you can see if it is working. Was handy when the gauge was showing overheating - turned out it was only 4 degrees high...

Answer (score 0):

1. Open air filter box and look for evidence of a rodent nest somewhere in the air intake. Is the air filter reasonably clean?
2. Depending on local fuel quality, is it time for a fuel filter change?
3. Look for a loose or cracked air duct between the output of the turbo and the engine.
4. What about clogged injectors? Try a dose of a good injector cleaner.